# regular expression to find last folder name in path

Tags: regex

I have the following path:

```
O:\Audits\Crisis Management 2016\2016 ECPR Final Report.pdf
```

And I need a regular expression that returns the name of the last folder (furthest to the right) in the path, which would be "**Crisis Management 2016**".

I have tried `(?:[^\\]*\\|^)[^\\]*$`, which is close, but that returns "**Crisis Management 2016\2016 ECPR Final Report.pdf**", which includes the trailing backslash and the file name.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try ``[^\\]+(?=\\[^\\]*$)``

Comment: You could split on a backslash or perhaps use a positive lookahead if that is supported `[^\\]+(?=\\[^\\]+$)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8SalCY/1) or a capturing group `([^\\]+)\\[^\\]+$`  [demo](https://regex101.com/r/8SalCY/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why * rather than + as we can not have a directory with no name?

Comment: @learnAsWeGo It is the pattern part from OP. I did not test it. There is just one sample string given, no test cases to check.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew true. +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
[^\\]+(?=\\[^\\]+\\?$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wNEdYu/1)

**Details**

- `[^\\]+` - 1+ chars other than `\`
- `(?=\\[^\\]+\\?$)` - a positive lookahead that requires `\`, 1+ chars other than `\` and then an optional `\` at the end of the string immediately to the right of the current location.

If you can easily access capturing groups and lookaheads are not supported use

```
([^\\]+)\\[^\\]+\\?$
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/wNEdYu/2).

The lookahead is turned into a consuming pattern and the first pattern is wrapped with capturing parentheses (forming Group 1 that keeps the submatch inside a memory buffer).

Comment: Thank you Wiktor Stribiżew!

Answer (score 0):

```
.*\\([^\\]+)\\
```

- **.*** means that we go-go...
- but when reached EOF step by step go back...
- and check the following (**\([^\]+)\**) condition;
- then remember folder name in Capturing Group;
- thats it.